# Removing rows with same foreign key but with different values

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table with similar structure to the following:

[image]

I am looking for a way to remove all rows where role_id = 4, in cases where there is already a row with the same context_id and user_id and where the role_id = 3.

for example this row should be removed:
[image]

Since there is already a row with the same context_id, user_id and where the role_id = 3

Comment: What has this to do with foreign keys?

Comment: @P.Salmon Perhaps the `context_id` is a foreign key?  I agree that the title does not get to the meat and potatoes of the problem.

Comment: I had some trouble figuring out the title, and i thought to write "foreign key" because the combination of user_id and context_id provide a sort of a foreign key in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `DELETE` self join:

```
DELETE t1
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.context_id = t2.context_id AND
       t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND
       t2.role_id = 3
WHERE
    t1.role_id = 4;
```

This matches rows from your table under the following conditions:

- the `context_id` matches to another `context_id`, and the `user_id` also matches
- the left side record has `role_id` of 4 and the right side record has `role_id` of 3

Comment: I don't think this fits what i want to accomplish, you did not take the role_id into account

Comment: @RealGigex I had `user_id` as a typo for `role_id`.  Other than this, the query should work.

Comment: But the way to identify the rows (a kind of foreign key) depends on both context_id and user_id which is now missing.

Comment: I added a check on `user_id` to the query.